# Cannot get my python script to print pdfs in original order in file directory

Tags: python, sorting, printing

I am very new to python and I have been tasked with creating a script to print all pdfs in a set directory in the same order as they are in the directory

I was able to accomplish getting the script top run, however when it prints the pdfs they are not in the same order as there were originally in the directory. For example I have (15) pdf named 1, 2, 3, etc. And it prints them in an order of 1,11,12,13,14,15,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

I have seen a lot of talk about using sort method or natsort, I cam across the winsort method which seemed to to do the trick I thought. However it shows the correct order when the script runs and on the output, but on the printer queue they are still out of order and random.

*** SCRIPT CODE BELOW***

```
# Import libraries
import os
import time

from ctypes import wintypes, windll
from functools import cmp_to_key

def winsort(data):
    _StrCmpLogicalW = windll.Shlwapi.StrCmpLogicalW
    _StrCmpLogicalW.argtypes = [wintypes.LPWSTR, wintypes.LPWSTR]
    _StrCmpLogicalW.restype  = wintypes.INT

    cmp_fnc = lambda psz1, psz2: _StrCmpLogicalW(psz1, psz2)
    return sorted(data, key=cmp_to_key(cmp_fnc))


# Insert the directory path in here
path = 'T:\Mail Room\Suits To Print\VA\Batch 1'

# Extracting all the contents in the directory corresponding to path
l_files = winsort (os.listdir(path))

# Iterating over all the files
for file in l_files:

# Instantiating the path of the file
    # file_path = f'{path}\\{file}'
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
    # Checking whether the given file is a directory or not
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        try:
            # Printing the file pertaining to file_path
            os.startfile(file_path, 'print') 
            print (f'Printing {file}')

            # Sleeping the program for 3 seconds so as to account the
    # steady processing of the print operation.
            time.sleep(3)
        except:
            # Catching if any error occurs and alerting the user
            print(f'ALERT: {file} could not be printed! Please check\
            the associated softwares, or the file type.')
    else:
        print(f'ALERT: {file} is not a file, so can not be printed!')
        
print('Task finished! 'Print Job Completed. Please release job from printer')
```

*** OUTPUT BELOW** Showing in order as I want.

Example how they look in the output which is correct. but the printer queue is not correct. I assume I need to sort somewhere else before they make it to the print queue??

```
[Running] python -u "t:\Document Retrieval\SUITS\# Import libraries.py"
Printing 1.PDF
Printing 2.PDF
Printing 3.PDF
Printing 4.PDF
Printing 5.PDF
Printing 6.PDF
Printing 7.PDF
Printing 8.PDF
Printing 9.PDF
Printing 10.PDF
Printing 11.PDF
Printing 12.PDF
Task finished!Print Job Completed. Please release job from printer

[Done] exited with code=0 in 37.137 seconds
```

** PRINT QUEUE**

[image: print queue image or the order]

I tried added the sort, natsort, and winsort function to sort them and print in  numerical order printing 1-15. However it still shows the correct order in the output, but incorrect order on the print queue.

Comment: Is it actually finishing submitting the job to the print queue before the next job is started? I ask because the documentation for `os.startfile()` says `startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status.` So even if winsort() works correctly, the jobs could still be submitted out of order.

Comment: Didnt think about that, but if its sending each job one at a time, and they are in the correct order when opening and printing? why are they in a random order at time of print. Banging my head against the wall on this.

Comment: Does the document get 'spooled' on the local user's computer, or on a print server? The print server could be receiving jobs into a queue, and then spooling them out of order. (e.g. see [this SpiceWorks forum thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/82029-spooled-documents-printing-out-of-order-any-advice))

Comment: There's a simple way to check this theory - add a ten second wait between each job. If that fixes the re-ordering, then this is a race condition.

Comment: See also [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/203965/print-windows-print-jobs-in-order-of-submission)

Comment: These jobs are currently being sent to a print server software called papercut. I will try the 10 second delay and see if that makes a change

Comment: The 10 second delay did the trick! thanks now I need to search this race condition

Comment: you may not be able to fix the race if it's in the serverside implementation and instead step outside its logic and (for example) check the length of the print queue to see that it's empty .. you may also find a suitable delay works for the general case (though it may fail for trivial conditions like running out of paper)