# Python script that prints all word files in directory prints the documents out of order

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have a short Python script that looks in the directory I point it to and prints all of the files in it (Microsoft Word .docx format).

The entire script is below:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path


#set path where the files to print are
my_path = Path(__file__).parent / 'OUTPUT'
string_path = str(my_path)

#list all files in chosen folder
list_files = os.listdir(my_path)

#make the list of files into a list of paths
list_paths = [os.path.join(str(my_path), file) for file in list_files]

#this function prints everything in the folder using the paths
def print_all():
    for item in list_paths:
        os.startfile(item, "print")

#run the print function
print_all()
```

It works, as in it sends all the files to the default network printer and they do print, but the files are not in order when they come of the printer, although they are ordered in the directory by filename as such:

01_firstdoc.docx 
02_seconddoc.docx 
03_thirddoc.docx 
..etc.. 
20_twentiethdoc.docx

I read the following posts ([post on out of order printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75525543/cannot-get-my-python-script-to-print-pdfs-in-original-order-in-file-directory); [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439458/files-print-to-physical-printer-out-of-order-using-python)), where one had no response, and another (first post) had some comments suggesting to add a wait time. However, I am not sure how to implement that, or if that is indeed the solution to this problem in my case. And while I understand the delay concept reasoning, I am also not sure about the race condition mentioned in the comments.

Running Windows 10 Home, and Python 3.10.5

Edit: Adding time.sleep() to the for loop has fixed the issue, as suggested below.

```
def print_all():
    for item in list_paths:
        os.startfile(item, "print")
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Does `list_files` contain the file names in right order (probably not)? If not, the list should be `sort`ed before further processing. A wait time can be implemented with function `sleep` from module `time`.

Comment: I tried putting a print statement into the for loop, and it returned the paths in the correct order, so I thought that they were also in the right order in the lists (unless I'm misunderstanding something). I will try to see if the sorted() function and/or the time module make a difference with the printing.

Comment: If they were ordered correctly in the for-loop, `sort(ed)` won't help.

Comment: Ah... was afraid that would be the answer.

Comment: Using time.sleep seems to have fixed the issue! I had forgotten about the sorted() function as well, so will remember for the future, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the delay, you just need to import `time`

then call `time.sleep(10)` (the number represents the seconds) in your code, right behind `os.startfile(item, "print")`

Check if it works to you. It seemed to help the person of the 2nd thread you mention.

And about the order, make sure you are actually ordering the paths and do: `for item in sorted(list_paths):`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I put an example of the working for loop in an edit in the post, in case anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Files in a directory are not sorted in any order naturally; when you look at them with `ls`, the sorting is done by `ls`, not the OS or file system. (And you can change how it sorts them with options.)

Just sort the array in your Python program (e.g. `for item in sorted(list_paths):`.

Comment: Although this seems to not have been the issue in my case, I was not sure about the sort mechanics and how files work in the file system (still learning), so will keep this suggestion in mind for other cases in the future, thanks!